# What is the way to solve this ImportError for name 'handle_message_parameters'?

Tags: discord, discord.py

My Code according to error is :

```py
import re, os, asyncio, random, string, keep_alive, discord

from discord.ext import commands, tasks
```

This is the starting of the code .

Error goes as :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 1, in <module> 
import re, os, asyncio, random, string, keep_alive, discord

from .client import Client File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python 3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 53, in <module>

from .webhook import Webhook File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8

from .async_ import *

File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python 3.8/site-packages/discord/webhook/async_.py ", line 46, in <module>

from ..http import Route, handle_message_parameters, MultipartParameters, HTTPClie

nt, json_or_text
 ImportError: cannot import name 'handle_mes sage_parameters' from 'discord.http' (/opt/ virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-pack ages/discord/http.py)

exit status 1
```

Can't have a clue .

Comment: Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported in [this issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/8038). Try to reinstall the module again by using `pip install discord.py`. Make sure to update the `pip` to the latest version just in case.

Comment: thanks for your help @Iqrar99 . I did what you said but it made no difference still . Idk why !